# Near-identical code causes errors?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

So I have 2 lines of extremely similar code. Here is the first line (which has no problems):

```
Player.Tex = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Textures\d");
```

And here is the second line (which has a TypeInitializationException)

```
HealthPickup.Tex = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Textures\healthPickup");
```

In the Player class and the HealthPickup class there is a line just after public class with this:

```
public static Texture2D Tex;
```

So why is my HealthPickup class causing this error? Have I missed something obvious? I have tried searching for the exception but nothing helps.

EDIT: As requested, my HealthPickup class is as follows:

http://pastebin.com/RXZ2xh1e

Also, my Player class:

http://pastebin.com/XKuVXPk3

Notice that my HealthPickup class is identical to my Player class apart from 4 variables, (Tex, Dir, Pos and speed in Player and Tex, randX, randY, Pos in HealthPickup)

Comment: What's the exception message?

Comment: @48klocs 'The type initializer for 'TestGame.HealthPickup' threw an exception.' That's all it gives me.

Comment: Show the code for your `TestGame.HealthPickup` class - it is clearly throwing an exception in the constructor or field initializer.

Comment: @DavidHaney Okay I edited the question to accomodate your request.

Comment: Okay I've found the problem. It was my attempt at random map placement. I wanted it to appear at a random position on the map each time but obviously that didn't work out. I'd still like some help on how to do that though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to convert an object of type `Random` to an integer. This is not allowed. You can get a random number from `Random` object using one of the `Next` method overloads. Like so :

```
(new Random (Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode())).Next()
```

using `Guid.NewGuid()...` is not obligatory, but will make sure you get 2 `Random` objects with different seeds

Comment: I thought generating the random numbers then converting them to Int32's would work. Obviously not.

Comment: `Random.Next` method returns a random integer so no conversion is needed. `Random`'s constructor initializes a new instance of the `Random` class which cannot be converted to integer. see [Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) on MSDN

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was these lines in my HealthPickup class:

```
public static int randX = Convert.ToInt32(new Random(1));
public static int randY = Convert.ToInt32(new Random(1));
public static Point Pos = new Point(randX, randY);
```

Apparently Point() doesn't like random numbers so I changed it to this:

```
public static Point Pos = new Point(50, 50);
```

### Problem Solved

Comment: Actually, Converting a new `Random` class to an integer was your problem. `Convert.ToInt32(object)` fails when object is not an integer.

Comment: You need to do `Random r = new Random` and then `Point Pos = new Point(r. Next(0, 50)), randY. Next(0,50));` Currently you are using the same seed for both numbers and not creating them correctly.